# Documentation for pgfplots expressions?

Tags: pgfplots, documentation

Is there documentation for which functions work as `pgfplots` expressions (like sin, cos, exp, etc.)  The `pgfplots` documentation doesn't seem to say anything on what you can/can't use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`pgfplots`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/pgfplots.html) package uses `pgfmath` expressions from the [`pgf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html) package. See the TikZ/PGF manual ([`pgfmanual.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)) in part VI, section 63 "Syntax for mathematical expressions", page 527 in PGF v2.10 for a list of all available PGF math expressions. You can also add your own, but some programming is required for that.

In the current TikZ/PGF manual (version (3.15b) "Syntax for Mathematical Expressions" starts in Part VIII, section 95 on page 1026 in the [`pgfmanual.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure that pgfplots uses all the pgfmath functions of the pgf 2.1 version. I have the impression that pgfplots uses the functions of pgf 2.0 and I'm not sure that you can use in pgfplots a personal function created with pgfmathdeclarefunction. Perhaps I'm wrong but if you have an example I think a lot of users will be happy ! I have some difficulties with the english language but there is pgfplotstodo document somewhere ...

Comment: @Altermundus: AFAIK `pgfplots` passes the math expressions to `pgf` in whatever version installed and uses the return value. This would allow for all available functions including self-defined ones. However, I didn't tested that by myself.

Comment: I sent an email to Christian Feuersaenger. I hope he has enough time to give an answer because my first tests are negative.

Comment: PGFPlots uses the fpu library of pgf -- which is supposed to contain all math functions. But it might happen that some new functions need to be ported to the fpu. Can you send me an example? Perhaps I can improve some things.

Comment: @Feuersaenger: I think you mean Altermundus, don't you? You need to add `@Altermundus` in your comment so that he gets notified.

Comment: Some of those functions maybe are not yet available? recalling one of the comments of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/336520/177: `isprime`, `iseven`, `gcd`, `frac`, `random`, `setseed`, `Mod`, `div`, `real` are not yet implemented. (See pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)