# Tikz Math div error

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code that work fine in standalone but it give the following error when it is embedded in my article

```
Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'div' has not yet been implemented in the floating point unit (in '{-1-div(1,4)}'). }
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }
```

The working code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=1mm,circle},
]
\node[cnode=white,draw=green,label=0:$O_1$] (s1) at (6,-3.25) {};
\node[cnode=white,draw=green,label=0:$O_2$] (s2) at (6,-2.25) {};
\node at (0.0,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (1,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (2,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (4.0,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (5,-4) {$\vdots$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
    \node[cnode=white,draw=blue,label=180:$x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at  (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=white,draw=orange,label=90:] (A-\x) at (1,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=white,draw=orange,label=90:] (B-\x) at (2,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=white,draw=orange,label=90:] (C-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=white,draw=orange,label=90:] (D-\x) at (4,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \node[cnode=white,draw=orange,label=90:] (E-\x) at (5,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
    \draw (E-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.53] {} (s1);
    \draw (E-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {} (s2);

}
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
{   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
    {   \draw (x-\x) -- (A-\y);
        \draw (A-\x) -- (B-\y);
        \draw (B-\x) -- (C-\y);
        \draw (C-\x) -- (D-\y);
        \draw (D-\x) -- (E-\y);
    }
}

\node[above=.1cm] at (A-1) {$H_1$};
\node[above=.1cm] at (B-1) {$H_2$};
\node[above=.1cm] at (C-1) {$H_3$};
\node[above=.1cm] at (D-1) {$H_4$};
\node[above=.1cm] at (E-1) {$H_5$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the article preamble

```
\documentclass[%
draft,
%submission,
%compressed,
%final,
%
%technote,
%internal,
%submitted,
%inpress,
%reprint,
%
%titlepage,
notitlepage,
%anonymous,
narroweqnarray,
inline,
twoside,
    %invited,
]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[]{mcode}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc, fpu, decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{subeqn}{0}}% Reset subequation number    at start of align
\newcounter{subeqn} \renewcommand{\thesubeqn}{\theequation\alph{subeqn}}%
\newcommand{\subeqn}{%
\refstepcounter{subeqn}% Step subequation number
\tag{\thesubeqn}% Label equation
}
 \makeglossaries 
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: please post a document that produces the error that you ask about. A document with no error and a partial fragment that can not be run make it hard to debug the error that you say you get!

Comment: Don't use `div` instead use `\x/4`

Comment: @percusse I thought that, but what's the "working" code doing? ah the fp code...

Comment: Perhaps the same bug as [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331803/51022). Package [tag:pgfplots] forbids the following functions: `isprime`, `iseven`,  `gcd`, `frac`, `random`, `setseed`, `Mod`, `div`, `real`. (See `pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex`)

Comment: By the way, `div` is integer division, I am not surprised if it is forbidden by Floating Point Unit Library.

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes, but the problem is that you can't turn floating point *off*. If you load it, you're stuck with it always. That is, it should be possible to switch it off and use those functions in pictures where floating point isn't needed.

Comment: I asked a [question about this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328996/how-can-the-effects-of-pgfkeys-pgf-fpu-true-be-reversed) a while ago which Symbol1 answered. But it is really a bug as far as I can see - and quite a significant one.

Comment: @cfr `\begin{axis}[use fpu=false,...` (a bit late to the party)

Comment: @HenriMenke Won't that switch it off at most for that `axis` environment? What if I want to switch it off for a `tikzpicture`? Unless the bug has been fixed, that isn't possible. (I don't know about the `pgfplots` switch off: perhaps that works differently and doesn't share the bug.)